# Angular 2 - Receiving a POST Response Header with Content-Length > 0 but no content

Tags: angular, http-post, angular2-services

With Angular 2 I'm using Http.post() to retrieve some JSON data. When I use cURL or HttpRequestor everything works correctly. However, with Angular I'm getting a Response Header with Content-Length > 0 but the Response itself has no data.

```
public retrieveJsonData() {
    var url = 'https://somewhere.com/whatever/GetItem?token=XXXX&resource=YYYY&data=%7B%22id%22%3A2207%7D';
    let options = new RequestOptions({});

    return this.http
        .post(url, '', options)
        .map(result => result.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Request Headers:

```
POST /whatever/GetItem?token=XXXX&resource=YYYY&data=%7B%22id%22%3A2207%7D HTTP/1.1
Host: somewhere.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:8888/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 22:49:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
Set-Cookie: Foo=6djdhg7pnsqavk0nqa83u7rqt6; path=/; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1311
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/json
```

So in this example the Content-Length = 1311 but the response is empty. If I use a tool like HttpRequester the POST works as expected and the response is 1311 characters. What is going on?

Comment: You can see response body in your browser developer tools like firebug, if response is correct, then it means you have error in your code. It looks like you want to use GET, but current method is POST.

Comment: The request and response headers above are copied directly from Firebug. A POST request is required for this call and works correctly in environments other than Angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do post requests

```
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({firstName:'Joe',lastName:'Smith'}),{headers:headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe((res:Person) => this.postResponse = res);
```

Try this after replacing with your values.